# Allow VM to be accessed outside host machine only via port

Tags: windows, networking, nat, port-forwarding, vmware-workstation

I have a VM A and VM B running on a host machine H. Both these VM are using NAT. What I want is that this VM to be accessible to outside machine within the same network but only via particular ports. For example lets say machine XYZ wants to access the VMs it should only be able to access the VM through a specific port through the HOST-IP::PORT.

This is what I have done to perform [this](http://www.virten.net/2013/03/how-to-setup-port-forwarding-in-vmware-workstation-9/).

```
Lets say my VM IP is 1.2.3.4

In vmware workstation 
-> edit
-> Network editor
-> Vmnet8(NAT) NAT settings
-> Port Forwaring Add 
-> Host Port 9191, Type TCP, VM IP 1.2.3.4, VM Port 5001
Then in the vm
-> Firewall setting allowed incoming from port 5001
```

But now from my XYZ machine when I try to ping HOSTIP:port i cannot successfully ping it.

Answer (score 1):

Ping uses icmp and has no concept of a port. So you are just pinging your host machine.

If you are on windows, You can use telnet.

`telnet HOSTIP 9191`

Telnet is available under Turn Windows features on or off.

This will at least test the port forward.

Note if it connects the screen will seem to "go black" or show some text depending on the service. If it does not say `connection failed`, then it is working.

Comment: it is a windows os

Comment: nmap is available for windows as well. Telnet is definitely available under Turn Windows features on or off. I edited my answer.

Comment: I tried telnet hostIP WrongPort and I get an error saying "could not open connection to host on port". Now when i try telnet hostIP correctPort it clears the console and i see a blinking cursor. Thats it. Does this mean its working ?

Comment: Yep if it clears like that then it connected.